# Why is my function called twice in storage.single?

Tags: node.js, multer

I don't know why but my function is called twice in `storage.single`.

```js
app.post("/upload-file", async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        export const inMemoryStorage = (opts = {}) => {
          return multer({ storage: multer.memoryStorage(), ...defaultOpts, 
          ...opts })
         }

        const storage = inMemoryStorage();
        storage.single('file')(req, res, () => {
         console.log(req.file) // in my last update
         console.log('called') // this is returned two times
         return this.uploadService.uploadFile(req)
          })
        } catch (err) {
           next(err);
        }
     });
}
```

Thank you if you have the solution. I just want my function to be called once.

---- New edit ----

So my uploadService is like this :

```
  async uploadFile(req) {

    const b2 = new B2({
      applicationKeyId: 'private1',
      applicationKey: 'private2'
    })

    const upload = await b2.getUploadUrl({ bucketId: 'my-private-key' })

    const myfile = await b2.uploadFile({
      uploadUrl: upload.data.uploadUrl,
      uploadAuthToken: upload.data.authorizationToken,
      fileName: getFilename(req.file),
      data: req.file.buffer,
      onUploadProgress: (event) => null
    })

    console.log(myfile) // it works

    return myfile

  }
```

So my upload work, and I can see my console.log. So in my database, like 15s after the first upload, another file is sended from my method and my console.log return me twice objets

---------- Last Update ----------

I note something, I don't know why, but when my file is bigger than 50mb. My function is called 2 times. And under 50mb, everything is correct and I send only one time my file

As you can see, I added console.log(req.file). And the result is :

```
{
  fieldname: 'file',
  originalname: 'myMovie.mp4',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'video/mp4',
  buffer: <Buffer 1a 45 df a3 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 23 42 86 81 01 42 f7 81 01 42 f2 81 04 42 f3 81 08 42 82 88 6d 61 74 72 6f 73 6b 61 42 87 81 04 42 85 81 02 18 53 80 ... 107390076 more bytes>,
  size: 107390126
}
{
  fieldname: 'file',
  originalname: 'myMovie.mp4',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'video/mp4',
  buffer: <Buffer 1a 45 df a3 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 23 42 86 81 01 42 f7 81 01 42 f2 81 04 42 f3 81 08 42 82 88 6d 61 74 72 6f 73 6b 61 42 87 81 04 42 85 81 02 18 53 80 ... 107390076 more bytes>,
  size: 107390126
}
```

So my two req.file is the same

Comment: can you post full code ? for ex - what is this.uploadService?

Comment: You may have to use semicolons like each JavaScript user. It will probably fix itself, providing you're doing `const storage = inMemoryStorage()storage.single ...` in theory.

Comment: I did an update to show you my uploadService. And I don't thinks it's my semicolons cause it's on two lines. But I added one just to be sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I see the problem in your updated code examples. You are not sending the response back to the client in the `upload-file` route handler and this is causing the browser to resend the request.

Modify handler as follows

```
app.post("/upload-file", async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        export const inMemoryStorage = (opts = {}) => {
          return multer({ storage: multer.memoryStorage(), ...defaultOpts, 
          ...opts })
         }

        const storage = inMemoryStorage();
        storage.single('file')(req, res, () => {
         console.log(req.file) // in my last update
         console.log('called') // this is returned two times
            await this.uploadService.uploadFile(req);
            res.sendStatus(200); // or equivalent
          })
        } catch (err) {
           next(err);
        }
     });
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, you found the solution!!

Answer (score 0):

Along with debug message `called` try to add following.

```
console.log(new Error().stack);
```

That will help you identify where the redundant/duplicate call is coming from.

Comment: Thank you for your response but I see nothing in the console.log that could help me. Everything is normal

Answer (score 0):

First of all, uploadFile is an async function, so storage.single code should look like

```js
storage.single('file')(req, res, async () => {
    console.log('called')
    return await this.uploadService.uploadFile(req)
})
```

also, what if the callback is sending you back an error?

```js
storage.single('file')(req, res, async (err) => {
    if (err) {
        // handle err
    }
    console.log('called')
    return await this.uploadService.uploadFile(req)
})
```

Now, I'm not sure how you are using this in the api.

Based on how I've handled file uploads previously,

```js
function fileParser(req, res, opts = {}) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        multer({ storage: multer.memoryStorage(), ...defaultOpts, ...opts })
        .single("file")(req, res, (err) => {
            if (err) {
               return reject(err);
            }
            return resolve();
        });
    });
}

async function fetchAndUploadFile(req, res, opts = {}) {
    await fileParser(req, res, opts);
    await uploadService.uploadFile(req);
}

// usage in api route 

app.post("/your-route", async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        await fetchAndUploadFile(req, res);
        // other api logic & return response
    } catch (err) {
        next(err);
    }
});
```

Try this out and let me know if it helps. Also, are you using express or some other framework like feathers? (Asking cause I've seen similar queries when feathers framework is being used)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried exactly like your code, but I got the same issue. But I note something, I don't know why, but when my file is bigger than 50mb. My function is called 2 times. And I just use express in my backend

Comment: Quite interesting. Can you confirm that the API is not getting called twice in this scenario? I think it might not be the case but better check. Maybe if the file-size is larger than a certain size, the frontend is dividing it into multiple chunks and calling the API for each chunk. Not sure of this but you can check.

Comment: Also, if possible, I'll suggest using signed-urls for uploading files. This way, you'll be putting less stress on your API server.

Comment: Are you putting this upload service behind an express app? How and when are you seeing the log message twice. i.e. How do you produce it? Doings file upload via browser? If it is sitting behind an express app can to show the endpoint implementation?

Comment: Thank you for your response @jeeves So it's just a route, not an app in express. I just use an await to get my data. My file is uploaded from a browser (chrome), and for a file under 50mb, everything work perfectly it's weird.

Comment: Thank you @BhumilSarvaiya. I don't think is my front end, cause if I turn off my frond end just after the upload, my console.log is still called twice. And even if I delete my method for really send my my file, the two console.log is still here

Comment: A couple more questions/ comments. Can you log a timestamp to when the two logs are being printed. The reason I ask this is, if you don't send a response back to a post request within a certain time (or at all), the browser will resend the request. Because the file size is relatively large, 50mb it could be the case that your route is not ending the request (by sending a response back to the browser) quickly enough and the browser is resending the request. I've had a similar bug and it was very hard to track down as the resending of the request is not logged in Chrome Dev tools.